# what are the safety requirements for scraping old drylock?

Tags: basement, safety

One basement wall is in pretty good shape, just going to wet and lightly scrape before painting with new Drylok.  Other walls are pretty bad, flaking and such.

I have 3M 8210 n95 masks, is that sufficient for scraping old Drylock ?  Going to find a way to ventilate the basement too.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is around these walls but I have always used really really hot water - boiling if I can (turn up that water heater) and a tiny bit of bleach per bucket.   Get paint wet and hot and it scrapes off much easier.  I see no reason for even a mask using this method... If you are going to dry sand it with a metallic brush then yes mask - I would never do that though for a basement wall.

Comment: @DMoore a steamer should do the trick, too. Might not want to breath steamed bleach, though...

Comment: @DMoore - whats the reason for not using a metalic brush?  the good section - sure, but the bad sections its all flaking off.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary concern would be with any lead-containing coating *beneath* the Drylok. Your secondary consideration should be for silica.

According to the CDC, an N95 is **NOT** adequate for lead dust, you need a P-100 or equivalent rating on your respirator.

For airborne silica dust, an N95 is acceptable.

So if you are relatively confidant that there isn't an old lead-containing coating beneath the Drylok, the N95 would be sufficient.